# get post field by JavaScript

Tags: javascript

as you know we can get post field by server side language like php,for example in php

```
$var1 = $_POST['field1']
```

now I wanna know is it possible to get it by JavaScript to?(or any Client Side Language like VBScript)

for example I have page which has got form

```
<form method = "post" action="test.php">
```

in test.php I wanna get field by JavaScript,not by php.
Is it possible and how can I do it if it's possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *cannot* read `$_POST` data using JavaScript.

When you submit data through the `GET` method, the generated query string can be read through the `location.search` object. Another method to "post" data from page 1 to page 2 is by using hashes.

**The `location` object** (JavaScript)

> `location.href` = `http://example.com/test.php?formElem=value&another=true#hash`
>   `location.search` = `?formElem=value&another=true`
>   `location.hash` = `#hash`

**Example** (based on the URL at the previous paragraph)

```
<script>
var $_GET = (function(){
    var query_string = location.search.substr(1); //Exclude the first character: `?`
    var data = query_string.split(/&+/); //
    var $_GET = {};
    for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
        var qs = data.match(/^([^=]+)(?:=(.*))?$/);
        $_GET[qs[1]] = qs[2];
    }
    return $_GET;
})()

alert($_GET["formElem"]); //Alerts "value"
</script>
```

An alternative method to transmit data from a form to a JavaScript HTML page is by using hashes:

```
<form action="index.html#someHash" method="get">
    <input type="submit" name="someName" value="someValue" />
</form>
```

After submission, the following page will be requested: `index.html?someName=someValue#someHash`
The `hash` is available through the `location.hash` property.

Comment: The from and JavaScript is not in the same file

Comment: @Moein7tl So, you want to read `$_POST` data at `not_submitted_here.php` from a submission to `test.php`?

Comment: for example I set action to "test.html" , now I need to get it by JavaScript to show.

Comment: @Moein7tl See my updated answer for an implementation of `$_GET`.

Answer (score 0):

in your test.php file, echo your post fields as a JSON object.

```
echo '<script> var data = '. json_encode($_POST).' </script>' ;
```

It can be accessed as a dictionary in javascript then.

Output in test.php

```
<script> 
 var data = { 'field1' : 'value1' , 'field2' : 'value2' } ;
 alert(data['field1']);
</script>
```

Comment: I don't wanna use php,I wanna make JavaScript to do it and copy/past it in other pages